# R outer with if condition

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

Using R, I am defining a matrix M filled with 0 expect for the diagonal `M(i,i)` and `M(i,i-1)` and `M(i,i+1)` elements.

Since this matrix can be quite big, I wanted to use the outer function.
However, if I define `makeM` function like this:

```
makeM <- function(j,k,n,s){
    a=j*(n-j)*(1.0-s)/n^2
    b=j*(n-j)*(1.0)/n^2
    if(j==(k+1)){ return(a)}
    if(j==(k-1)){ return(b)}
    if(j==k){ return(1-b-a)}
    return(0)
}
```

And try to apply outer:

```
N=100
M=outer(seq(1, N), seq(1,N), makeM,n=N,s=0.1)
```

I obtain the wring result, i.e. elements which should be null are not, as if the "if" condition dis not work in the outer.

To check, I did the same operation with brute force:

```
s=0.1
N=100
M=matrix(rep(0,N*N),ncol=N,nrow=N)
for(i in 1:N)
{
    for(j in 1:N)
    {
        M[i,j]=makeM(i,j,N,s)
    }
}
```

And this works, I obtain the right matrix. So the `makeM` function is OK.
So, it seems indeed that the problems lies in the vectorization of my "if" condition. However, I do not understand why. Could anyone explain why? And a way to pass a `if` statement in the outer function ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outer works with vectorized functions, so you just need to vectorize your function

```
VecFun <- Vectorize(makeM)
N=100
M=outer(seq(1, N), seq(1,N), VecFun,n=N,s=0.1)
```

Comment: Or even better, write the function in a way that makes it vectorized to begin with. Then this would be faster.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed a simple hack.

Comment: I also managed to vectorize directly the function as per @Roland 's suggestion:  

    `makeMbis <- function(j,k,n,s){  
        a=j*(n-j)*(1.0-s)/n^2  
        b=j*(n-j)*(1.0)/n^2  
        ifelse(j==(k+1),a,ifelse(j==(k-1),b,ifelse(j==k,1-a-b,0)))  
    }`

Answer (score -1):

I would advice you to create a sparse matrix.

Your brute-force approach with a lower n:

```
s=0.1
N=6
M=matrix(rep(0,N*N),ncol=N,nrow=N)
for(i in 1:N)
{
  for(j in 1:N)
  {
    M[i,j]=makeM(i,j,N,s)
  }
}
```

Now a solution creating a sparse matrix. Note how I substituted `j` with the corresponding sequence:

```
library(Matrix)
j <- seq_len(N) #sequence 1:N
M1 <- bandSparse(N, N, k = -1:1, diag= list(
  (j+1) *(N - (j+1))*(1.0-s)/N^2, #j offset by 1
  1-j*(N-j)*(1.0)/N^2-j *(N - j)*(1.0-s)/N^2,
  j*(N-j)*(1.0)/N^2
), symmetric = FALSE)
```

A sparse matrix needs less memory and is more efficient, but if you want, you can coerce it into a dense matrix:

```
M2 <- as.matrix(M1)
dimnames(M2) <- NULL
all.equal(M, M2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this, not directly replying my question but it may come in handy.

Comment: @z_fly_away If n becomes sufficiently large, this is the only solution that doesn't quickly run out of memory.